# How to store a variable history in django?

Tags: django, django-models, time-series

To simplify my problem, let's say I have a simple User model that happen to have an `IntergerField` containing a score in a game.

I'd like to store the time and the value of the score every time the core is modified. For example, let's say user A starts with score=0 when time=0, then wins 5 points at time=3. I'd change in the view the value of the score, but I'd also like to be able to query another attribute that would give me `{0:0, 3:5}`

The app will need to be used with MySQL, PostgresSQL and probably SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate model for the score, having at least `value` and `time` fields and a fkey to your user model. Then access the current score from the user by:

```
user.score_set.order_by('-time').first()
```

Comment: So property to access the score with `user.score_set.order_by('-time').first()`, and a UserScore model. Got it, thanks!