# How to order by a specific ForeignKey in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, foreign-keys

This is a kinda follow-up of this question: [How to store a variable history in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932662/how-to-store-a-variable-history-in-django/54932709#54932709)

To simplify my problem, let's say I have a simple Gamer that track users settings and data, and a specific UserScore model to track a tuple of `(time, score)`.

```
class GamerExperience(BasicModelProperties):
    gamer = models.ForeignKey('Gamer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='experience_history')
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    experience = models.BigIntegerField()
```

I would like to order every Gamer in the database by the highest (latest-score). Note that my Gamer model has a property that returns the latest score using `self.experience_history.order_by("-time").first().experience`

However, using sorted is really slow, and I'm sure there is another way to achieve that :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with class Meta?

```
class GamerExperience(BasicModelProperties):
    gamer = models.ForeignKey('Gamer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='experience_history')
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    experience = models.BigIntegerField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-gamer.score']
```